# Confused on how to return multiple results from query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following tables:

offers

| id | app_id | placed_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | '01-15-2020' |
| 2 | 25 | '02-04-2021' |
| 3 | 41 | null |

applications

| id | job_id | updated_at | submitted_date | status | person_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | '03-15-2017' | '03-02-2017' | 'reject' | 420 |
| 2 | 2 | '04-04-2018' | '04-01-2018' | 'reject' | 421 |
| 41 | 3 | '01-07-2019' | '12-31-2018' | 'placed' | 444 |

job_tags

| id | job_id | tag_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 'product management' |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 'data science' |
| 3 | 3 | 5 | 'design' |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 'data science' |

jobs

| id | title | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Eng manager' | 'Manager' |
| 2 | 'VP of data' | 'VP' |
| 3 | 'Vp of data and design' | 'VP' |

I would like to make a report returning the number of applications it takes to place a job, for each job, broken down by the type of job(ie product, data or design), as well as broken down by each level(ie manager level, vp level etc.)

I joined the tables as follows, but due to the joins, I get duplicate rows.
I've been trying to eliminate the duplicate rows by doing subreports on subsections of the joined table, but this is confusing.
Is it possible to eliminate the duplicate rows from my joins/any other advices?
Ideally, I would be able to return all of this information in one sql query, but the query feels too complicated to proceed.

```
offers2020 as (
    SELECT
        a.job_id,
        coalesce(o.accepted_date, a.status_updated_at) as placed_date
    FROM
        offers o
        inner join applications a on o.application_id = a.id
        and coalesce(o.accepted_date, a.status_updated_at) >= '2020-1-1'
        and coalesce(o.accepted_date, a.status_updated_at) < '2021-3-1'
),
apps2018 as (
    SELECT
        o.*,
        j.company_id,
        j.level,
        a.submitted_date as submit_date,
        a.status,
        a.person_id,
        a.id as app_id,
        j.title
    FROM
        offers2020 o
        inner join jobs j on j.id = o.job_id
        inner join applications a on a.job_id = j.id
),
apps2020ranked as (
    SELECT
        *,
        rank() over (
            partition by job_id
            order by
                submit_date asc
        ) as placed_index
    FROM
        apps2020 a
),
placed_ranks as (
    SELECT
        job_id,
        level,
        app_id,
        title,
        person_id,
        min(placed_index) as placed_index
    From
        apps2020ranked a
    where
        status = 'Placed'
    group by
        job_id,
        level,
        person_id,
        app_id,
        title
)
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    placed_ranks p
    inner join job_tags t on p.job_id = t.job_id
```

Edit:
Desired output

mean placed_index per month

| month | year | data_science | product_mgmt | design | vp_level | manager_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | 20 | 25 | 26.7 | 42 | 50 |
| 2 | 2020 | 22 | 23 | 21.7 | 50 | 43 |
| 3 | 2020 | 10 | 22 | 26 | 42 | 43 |
| 12 | 2020 | 15 | 20 | 23 | 42 | 44 |

Comment: What would desired output look like?

Comment: Desired output would be one table with monthly mean "placed_indexes" for every month in 2020, with columns as product_management, data science, design, manager, and vp.

Comment: Please post the actual desired output as formatted text not just a list of columns.

Comment: I posted the output, but my table is getting messed up by formatting